# OpenLDAP TLS Authentification

Tags: openldap, tls

I am trying to implement TLS as per https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html
When I try to modify cn=config database with this ldif file:

```
dn: cn=config
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/test-ldap-server_cert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/test-ldap-server_key.pem
```

I get the following error:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f certinfo.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
When I try to use simple auth I got the following error:

```
ldapmodify -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W -f certinfo.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
        additional info: invalid DN
```

Comment: Check the permissions on the certificate files. And also remove the password if such is set.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
The permissions are set to 644 except for .key file which is on 600
How do I check/remove password? I don't remember setting any password for cn=config..

Comment: I mean password on the certificate itself (not on cn=config). Check: https://mnx.io/blog/removing-a-passphrase-from-an-ssl-key/

Comment: No, that was not the case. The key file was created without password.

Comment: can you try to load the ldiff with simple auth (not -Y EXTERNAL)

Comment: I added the error I got when I try simple auth.
Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 18):

I was following the same guide and had the same issue. It will work if you do the steps to "Tighten up ownership and permissions" listed after the offending ldapmodify command first--namely:

```
sudo adduser openldap ssl-cert
sudo chgrp ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private
sudo chgrp ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/ldap01_slapd_key.pem
sudo chmod g+X /etc/ssl/private
sudo chmod g+r /etc/ssl/private/ldap01_slapd_key.pem
```

and

```
sudo systemctl restart slapd.service
```

Comment: This worked for me too!

Comment: In my case I had to use `chgrp openldap`. Anyway, it's a permission issue. +1

Comment: also private directory must be executable too in order to traverse. `sudo chgrp ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private && sudo chmod g+X /etc/ssl/private`

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know if this is a solution or just a workaround, but I managed to get it working.

I first stopped the slapd with:

```
service slapd stop
```

Then I started it in debug mode:

```
slapd -h ldapi:/// -u openldap -g openldap -d 65 -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d/ -d 65
```

Important is to start it ONLY with ldapi:/// URL. After it started I executed the ldapmodify command and the attributes were imported.

At the end I stopped the debug mode and started the slapd normally.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the problem is in apparmor profile for slapd service. Be sure that apparmor profile has allowed certificate paths for daemon.

It is quite visually in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.slapd`. By default this profile allows to read certificates in default locations.

Apparmor should prevent unspecified actions for daemon's executable, despite proper unix permissions.

Comment: If you use letsencrypt, this is the solution. Add the following lines to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.slapd`:

    /etc/letsencrypt/ r,
    /etc/letsencrypt/** r,

and reload the apparmor profiles.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow-up to [A. Gutierrez's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/752105/356860), the best way to check access for each file is to run `sudo -u openldap cat <filename>`. I looked at all the files multiple times and they looked to have permissions set correctly. Turned out to be a group problem for openldap. Once I finally figured that out, a simple `sudo usermod -a -G ssl-cert openldap` solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

As I reported in [this bug on Ubuntu Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/1805178), this problem can also be caused by apparmor. Usually this will show in the syslog as an access denial.

The fix is inserting the following line in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.slapd:

`/etc/letsencrypt/** r,`

and then refreshing the profile:

```
# apparmor_parser -vr usr.sbin.slapd
# service apparmor restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem also. The problem is the user running slapd didnt has access to certs files. Check out that owner of that files is openldap user.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in wrong order of the records - here is the one that worked:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/cm_ca_cert.pem
-
# This never worked for me, no idea why
#add: olcTLSCipherSuite
#olcTLSCipherSuite: TLSv1+RSA:!NULL
#-
replace: olcTLSVerifyClient
olcTLSVerifyClient: never
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/cm_server.pem
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/cm_server.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this seems to be the "default" error you get for just about anything. @wulfsdad's anwser usually fixes it.

One other thing I always forget is that by default on ubuntu slapd wants the key in openssl format. I regulary but PCKS#8 keys into it and expect it to just work (which to be fair it should). If you tried all the anwsers above also make sure the key has the right format. When googling about the error you usually read about wrong permissions and rub your head why apache works with the very key slapd doesn't like.

Answer (score -1):

try to the following :

```
dn: cn=config

changetype: modify

replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile

olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem

-

replace: olcTLSCertificateFile

olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/test-ldap-server_cert.pem

-

replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile

olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/test-ldap-server_key.pem
```

Comment: Why do this though? Please explain what makes this a solution

Comment: did it work for you? you have to replace  the TLS attributes in the LDAP configuration with your configs.