# OpenLDAP TLS : ldap_modify error 80

Tags: debian, ssl, permissions, openldap, nfs4

I am trying to configure TLS on my LDAP server.
I have two computer, one with the LDAP server and another with an NFS share containing the Let's Encrypt generated certificates.

I want the first one to be able to read the certificates in the NFS mount.
I followed a tutorial one the Debian wiki : [here](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup#Configuring_TLS.2FSSL)

When I do `sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/olcTLS.ldif` I get :

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

Apparently this is a permission issue as seen [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/704822/openldap-tls-authentification)

Here is the content of the config file :

```
dn: cn=config
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /mnt/certs/chain.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /mnt/certs/privkey.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /mnt/certs/cert.pem
```

So I set the group of the NFS shared directory to `ssl-cert` and added read permission for it. (All sub-directories have full read permission for everyone).
Then on the LDAP server I have added the `openldap` user to the `ssl-cert` group. (The gid of `ssl-cert` is the same on both system).

I ran `sudo -u openldap -g ssl-cert ls -l /mnt/certs` and it worked. The `openldap` user is able to read files in the NFS mount.
So maybe it's not a permission issue after all... what do you think?

---

It would not have worked yesterday because there was errors in the paths and also Let's encrypt use symlinks, so there was no way the other system could access the files... I corrected it but it would not work either, so I tried reducing the margin of error just by copying the certificates on the LDAP server directly, in /tmp, and it still not working. I get the same error.

Comment: So AppArmor was preventing slapd to access /tmp. After fixing that, I was able to make it work. Now I have to make it work through the NFS share. The fact that it is not working with NFS is not related to AppArmor, and I tried without the symlinks and with full read permission, it is the same. So it is definitely a NFS related issue.